# How to run from PHP > Python > Matlab > Python > PHP

Tags: php, python, html, matlab, permissions

I'm trying to have PHP run a python script that runs matlab code. I want the matlab output (the value 7.5) to come back to PHP and output to the browser.

When I run my python script from the terminal, it successfully runs the matlab code.

When I run the python script from PHP, it does not output the matlab result to the browser. I should have "7.5" appear in the browser.

If I change the python code to just print something, then I get the correct output in the browser.

I suspect that I'm having an issue with permission, but I've given all of the files RWX permission to all.

HTML code

```
<form action='ts.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='submit' name='matlab_plot' value='Plot in Matlab'>
</form>
```

PHP code

```
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CS85_Project/troubleshoot/ts.py 2>&1');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.triarea(nargout=0)
a = eng.workspace['a']
print a
```

Matlab code

```
b = 5;
h = 3;
a = 0.5*(b.* h);
```

**EDIT:**
I have found that the python script stops running at `eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()` when called from PHP. I still don't have a solution to this problem, but my question is: why can't PHP run this python function?

Comment: my guess is that its a location problem, having python print out the current working directory and running the php script, or running the python script from the directory of the php script may illuminate the issue.

Comment: Try to let the python print the Matlab results, then output that printout using PHP.